# Can SonarQube analyse my project if it has files with .sah extension

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I need to analyse my project using sonar qube. It contains files with .sah extension but basically those .sah files contains javascript code.
I can analyse those files if i change files extensions from .sah to .js but its not a good way .
Is there a way with which I can analyse my code without changing extension from *.sah to *.js

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

`.sah` uses the standard JS syntax. You should be able to analyse sah files with the JavaScript plugin.

Add the following line in your sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.javascript.file.suffixes=.js,.sah
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set *sonar.javascript.file.suffixes* in the SonarQube UI, either globally or for a specific project.

The screenshot below shows the global setting.
You can either navigate through the UI to find the page, or use following URLs:

- global:  http://*your_SQServer*/admin/settings?category=javascript
- project level:  http://*your_SQServer*/project/settings?category=javascript&id=*your_project_id*

[image: setting javacript settings globally]